# How can I shuffle values between 2 columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a data set that contains 2 columns columns A is winning teams and column B is losing team I would like to shuffle the values between the 2 columns so when i start training the model the model can't predict the winning ream simply by looking at the winning team column

Before

```
A B
1 2
2 1
3 4
4 3
```

After

```
A B
1 2
2 1
4 3
3 4
```

Comment: These shouldn't be in your model at all anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to shuffle each row randomly

```
(pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x: np.random.choice(x,df.columns.size,replace = False),axis=1)
              .tolist(),
              columns = df.columns))
```

or

```
df.apply(np.random.permutation,axis=1,result_type='expand').set_axis(df.columns,axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   A  B
0  1  2
1  1  2
2  3  4
3  4  3
```